# Using Activated Route param variable in GET request returns null

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters, get, angular-httpclient

I have a component that is listening to an Observable that returns information based off of a name provided in a string.

I would like to provide the name to the Observable by passing in a variable of the Activated Route parameter in the GET request. The problem is that when I use the variable within my GET request in the service, the URL is not detecting my variable and the request returns 'null'.

I suspect that my problem lies within my ngOnit in my component. The `playerCode` in my `getPlayer(playerCode)`.. I'm just not sure why..

If my playerCode is a string and I append that to my URL in the request, shouldn't that work?

In my component:

```
ngOnInit() {

const playerCode = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('player');  

this.playerService.getPlayer(playerCode).pipe(
  switchMap( player => { 
   let playerData = player["data"][0];
   let anotherID = playerData.id;

   return this.playerService.getSeasonStats(anotherID);

 })) 

 .subscribe(id => this.player = id);


 }
```

My Service that is using string variable in the URL:

```
 getPlayer(player: string):Observable<Player[]> {

let getHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'API_Key', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'}); 

  return this.http.get<Player[]>(`https://api.pubg.com/shards/steam/players?filter[playerNames]=`+ player,  { observe:'body',   responseType: 'json', headers: getHeaders,  });    

  }
```

My app-routing component

```
 const routes: Routes = [

 { path: 'players', component: CareerComponent },
 { path: 'players/:player', component: CareerComponent },
 {  path: '**', redirectTo: 'players'  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your routing. It will match the first route first so your dynamic variable will be ignored. Change your routing to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [

 { path: 'players', pathMatch: 'full', component: CareerComponent },
 { path: 'players/:player', component: CareerComponent },
 {  path: '**', redirectTo: 'players'  }
```

This will ensure that when your url is `players/0203` it would match the second route and not the first one.

Comment: Appreciate the response! Just tried this but I'm still seeing `https://api.pubg.com/shards/steam/players?filter[playerNames]=null` though :(

Comment: created a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qrsy7

Comment: Argh, so I missed something really stupid  >.< I commented out my <router-outlet> thing in my app-component.. Both of your answers helped, but I am marking C_Ogoo's as the answer as I didn't have the pathMatch in my Routes. Which might have also been also my problem. But thank you both :)

Answer (score 2):

---

Try to use

```
const routeparams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams
```

it will return an object of all the params and values and you can

then you can get the value of the player for your service with

```
routeparams['player']
```